# Is there a way to explicitly change an images source path using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

An HTML page handed off to me which originally have a image path which look something like this...

```
<img src="img/foo.jpg"
```

simply need to be changed to a new path.

I have a loop which goes through the collection of images:

```
container_images = container.getElementsByTagName('img');
             imgSrc = /img\//gi,

for (var i = 0; i < container_images.length; i++) {
    var images = container_images[i];

    if (images.src.indexOf('img') !== -1) {
        images.src = images.src.replace(imgSrc, 'new/path/here/');
    }
}
```

Now this works perfectly **locally** however when I run this on my company's QAF server, it appears the server is adding a dev path:

```
<img src="http://ryelxusecqcm1.rye.com:8080/us-home/tools/img/foo.gif">
```

So is there a method other than `.replace` which can explicitly wipe out and the old path and put my new path? i.e. `'new/path/here/'`

Comment: This is probably done for a reason, like serving static resources from a CDN or high-bandwidth server. You shouldn't be messing with this and instead talk to your server-side developer/sysadmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found such a simple but elegant solution. Instead of testing for a string with `indexOf` (which would've worked if I didn't have two different environments), I went for a solution which is more direct.

```
images.src = '/dam/avon-us/landing-pages/rep-news/' +  images.src.split('/').pop();
```

This first coverts the image path/string to a collection of items in an array, delineated by the forward slash. `['current', 'path', 'foo.jpg']` Then using the `pop` method return just the last item in the array, which is the file name & extension. `foo.jpg` and then we simply prepend the path we want the image to have!

Want to say thanks for all the folks who tried to help me!

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be because you are using a "relative" path in your code (i.e. a path that does not begin with "/"):

```
images.src = images.src.replace(imgSrc, 'new/path/here/');
```

Because you are using a relative path, your browser is prepending your path with the server's URL.

Try this and see if it helps.:

```
images.src = images.src.replace(imgSrc, '/new/path/here/');
```

(Note the leading "/" in '/new/path/here/')